# Multiple joined attribute selectors with single ":not()" vs Multiple separate attribute selectors with multiple ":not()"s in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, dom, css-selectors, selectors-api

I have 2 `<input>`s and tried to select `<input>`s by setting 2 joined attribute selectors to 1 `:not()` and 2 separate attribute selectors to 2 `:not()`s respectively with [querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) as shown below:

```html
<input type="text" name="first-name" id="fn" value="John">
<input type="text" name="last-name" id="ln" value="Smith">

<script>
                          // 2 joined attribute selectors to 1 ":not()"
document.querySelectorAll('input:not([name="first-name"][id="ln"])');

                          // 2 separate attribute selectors to 2 `:not()`s
document.querySelectorAll('input:not([name="first-name"]):not([id="ln"])');
</script>
```

Then, 2 joined attribute selectors with 1 `:not()` selects **John's `<input>`** and **Smith's `<input>`** and 2 separate attribute selectors with 2 `:not()`s selects **nothing** as shown below:

```js
                          // 2 joined attribute selectors to 1 ":not()"
document.querySelectorAll('input:not([name="first-name"][id="ln"])');
// John's <input> and Smith's <input>

                          // 2 separate attribute selectors to 2 `:not()`s
document.querySelectorAll('input:not([name="first-name"]):not([id="ln"])');
// Nothing
```

So, what is the difference between 2 joined attribute selectors with 1 `:not()` and 2 separate attribute selectors with 2 `:not()`s?

Comment: Because id attribute value have to be unique, it seems like `:not(#ln)` is enough

Comment: also this isn't so much a JavaScript question as it is a browser API question; the `.querySelectorAll()` function is not part of JavaScript the programming language.

Answer (score 1):

`input:not([name="first-name"][id="ln"])` selects both the input elements because no element on the page has both the name attribute set to "first-name" **and** id attribute set to "ln". Thus, all of them match. (`[name="first-name"][id="ln"]` matches nothing, so inverting that matches everything.)

`input:not([name="first-name"]):not([id="ln"])` selects nothing because there is only one element with the name attribute not set to "first-name", but its id attribute is "ln" which cannot match `:not([id="ln"])`.